# Laravel Eloquent: Access relationship of Original

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

In Laravel you can use `getOriginal()` on a model in order to get the original model (before changes since it was queried).

Now I need to access the relationship of that original model... is there a way to do that?

```
$item = OrderItem::where('id', $id)->with('qualification')->first();
$original_item = $item->getOriginal();
```

`$original_item["qualification"]` is not defined. I can access `qualification_id` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOriginal()` method returns array of the model's original attribute values, **it is not a model itself**, therefore you can not get a relationship.

So you can access the relationship using standard way: `$item->qualification`, that should not be affected by your changes of the parent model.